# Looping through a df of edges (x,y) to add attributes - too slow

Tags: performance, pandas, graph, while-loop, edges

I am fairly new to python and wrote the below loop to calculate a feature for a logistic regression.  It works, but it is extremely slow (approx 500k rows).

Basically, there are two dfs:
1. node_df is a df of nodes in Graph G, each with an attribute for dept
2. fc is a df of edges representing potential future connections.
   The index is (x,y) where (x,y) represents the edge from node x to node y.
I'm trying to add an attribute to each edge in fc which has a 1 if they are in the same dept (based on node_df) and 0 if they are not.  The code below works, but is very slow.  Is there a better way?

---

```
fc = pd.read_csv('Future_Connections.csv', index_col=0, converters={0: eval})

node_df = pd.DataFrame(index=G.nodes())
node_df['dept'] = pd.Series(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'Department'))

fc['common'] = 99
n = len(fc)
i = 0

while i < n:
    x = fc.ix[i].name[0]
    y = fc.ix[i].name[1]
    if node_df['dept'][x] == node_df['dept'][y]:
        fc['common'].loc[(x,y)] = 1
    else:
        fc['common'].loc[(x,y)] = 0
    i = i + 1
```

---

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you have two data frames. One is something like this:

```
            Future Connection
(6, 840)    0.0
(4, 197)    0.0
(620, 979)  0.0
```

And the other, something like this

```
    node    depth
0   6       2
1   840     2
2   4       3
3   197     4
4   620     5
5   979     5
```

First,

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'pairs'})
```

So we have

```
    pairs       Future Connection
0   (6, 840)    0.0
1   (4, 197)    0.0
2   (620, 979)  0.0
```

Now we can use `str.get` to get the first and second elements of each pair, and use `map` to check if their `depth` is the same.

For example,

```
df.pairs.str.get(0)
```

gives

```
0      6
1      4
2    620
```

If we `map` it with the second df,

```
df.pairs.str.get(0).map(df2.set_index('node').depth)

0    2
1    3
2    5
```

Now it is easy to compare the pairs depth

```
x = df.pairs.str.get(0).map(df2.set_index('node').depth) == df.pairs.str.get(1).map(df2.set_index('node').depth)

0     True
1    False
2     True


df["common"] = x.astype(int)


    pairs       Future Connection   common
0   (6, 840)    0.0                 1
1   (4, 197)    0.0                 0
2   (620, 979)  0.0                 1
```